# Variable to Set org-export pdf viewer

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I set which pdf viewer org-export uses when it exports to latex and pdf and views?

I'm using the command `C-c C-e l o` with default keybindings (Emacs 24.5). Currently it always uses xpdf, even though I am using pdf-tools and have set AUCTeX to use Zathura. I have also tried setting the `openwith-associations` variable to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `org-file-apps` is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
>
> Documentation: External applications for opening ‘file:path’ items in
>   a document. Org-mode uses system defaults for different file types,
>   but you can use this variable to set the application for a given file
>   extension.  The entries in this list are cons cells where the car
>   identifies files and the cdr the corresponding command.

Read the full documentation to find out the different ways to configure the variable.

A simple example would be something like this:

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf" . "some shell command %s"))
```

Comment: I ended up using the `customize` interface. Thank you!