# Org-mode Latex export opens pdf with GIMP

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Not sure why this is, but I just tried an org-mode Latex export (C-c C-e l o), but it opened GIMP to display my resulting pdf file. I'm on 27.1 and 9.4. My system is Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome. I went to org-file-apps and see `\.pdf\'` set to `Use default`. What are my best options to set the Ubuntu "document viewer" -- which is the default viewer throughout the system -- to be my org-mode Latex export viewer? So yes, the org-Latex interaction is healthy, just the strange choice Emacs/org-mode is making for my viewer. Obviously I could leave off the auto-open, but still...

Comment: This is a weirdness of Debain-based systems: `org-file-aps` defaults to looking up the app for a mime-type in the system `mailcap` files.  But, if `gimp` is installed on Debian and friends, it adds an entry in `mailcap` saying that it is the right thing to open pdf.  Strange but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue - the pdf was being opened within emacs itself rather than the default OS pdf viewer.

While I'm not sure how to get emacs to use the correct default OS apps, I fixed this by [changing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/variable-to-set-org-export-pdf-viewer) `("\\.pdf\\'" . default)` to `("\\.pdf\\'" . "atril %s")` in the `org-file-apps` list (atril is my pdf viewer).

---

Edit: (details on using the customize interface)

You simply have to change the string for "Command" where the "Extension" is `\.pdf\'` and then `State` -> "Save for Future Sessions":

[image]

There are instructions and examples below the `State` button for customizing this variable in particular.

Comment: The commenter of the OP together with this answer gave me what I needed. However, the Emacs customize page for `org-file-apps` is a bit cryptic on just how to add in the `("\\.pdf\\'" . "atril %s")`. I wound up just hand-adding into the `org-file-apps` section of my init.el. Nice would be if someone could explain how to navigate the customize page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fixing this in emacs, one can also change the system default. Emacs uses `/etc/mailcap`, probably through `run-mailcap`. `/etc/mailcap` gets refreshed by `/usr/sbin/update-mime`, so to influence what gets listed there first one has to edit `/etc/mailcap.order`.

I added one line there:

```
$ grep pdf /etc/mailcap.order
org.gnome.Evince:application/pdf
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/update-mime
```